# how to remove a duplicate word within a string , whereby this string is a value of an array?

Tags: php

how to remove a duplicate word within a string , whereby this string is a value of an array ?

e.g

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
   foreach($result as $words)
    {
        echo $words = str_word_count($words,0)."\n";
    }
}
```

result is e.g

```
test  = 1
test activity = 2
test CI to CGI = 4
Test car Pool = 3
```

what i want to happen is, e.g remove the other duplicates of the word "test" and list all the unqiue word so that the result will only be

```
test = 1
activity = 1
CI = 1
to = 1
CGI = 1
car = 1
pool = 1
```

Comment: Can you show print_r($results)

Comment: it's like `Array(0=>Array([WORD] => iphone, iphone3gs, 3gs,iphon 3 gs))` , something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
$final=array();

foreach($results as $result)
{
   foreach($result as $key=> $words)
    {
        echo $words = str_word_count($words,0)."\n";

       if(!in_array($words,array_keys($final))
           $final[$words]=str_word_count($words,0);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$results=array(
               array(
               "test",
               "test activity",
               "test CI to CGI",
               "Test car Pool"
               )
              );
$ws=array();
foreach($results as $result)
{
   foreach($result as $words)
    {
        $arr=explode(' ',$words);
        foreach($arr as $word)
        {
           if($word!='')
           {
              if(!isset($ws[$word])) $ws[$word]=1;
              else $ws[$word]++;
           }
        }
    }
}

print_r($ws);
```